# How to summarize values depending on category of other variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset which shows the religious adherence of Party A and Party B in X country, in addition to the percentage of religious adherents in each country.

```
df <- data.frame(
  PartyA = c("Christian","Muslim","Muslim","Jewish","Sikh"),
  PartyB = c("Jewish","Muslim","Christian","Muslim","Buddhist"),
  ChristianPop = c(12,1,74,14,17),
  MuslimPop = c(71,93,5,86,13),
  JewishPop = c(9,2,12,0,4),
  SikhPop = c(0,0,1,0,10),
  BuddhistPop = c(1,0,2,0,45)
)
#      PartyA    PartyB ChristianPop MuslimPop JewishPop SikhPop BuddhistPop
# 1 Christian    Jewish           12        71         9       0           1
# 2    Muslim    Muslim            1        93         2       0           0
# 3    Muslim Christian           74         5        12       1           2
# 4    Jewish    Muslim           14        86         0       0           0
# 5      Sikh  Buddhist           17        13         4      10          45
```

With this, I want to add together the total sum of "involved" religious adherents. So row one would get a variable equal to 12 + 9, row two only 93 (no addition since Party A and Party B are the same), etc.

```
#      PartyA    PartyB ChristianPop MuslimPop JewishPop SikhPop BuddhistPop PartyRel
# 1 Christian    Jewish           12        71         9       0           1       21
# 2    Muslim    Muslim            1        93         2       0           0       93
# 3    Muslim Christian           74         5        12       1           2       79
# 4    Jewish    Muslim           14        86         0       0           0       86
# 5      Sikh  Buddhist           17        13         4      10          45       55
```

I'm having a hard time even finding where to begin, and help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can iterate through rows with `sapply`, then `paste` the string "Pop" to your `Party` columns for indexing and summation.

```r
df$PartyRel <- sapply(
  1:nrow(df), 
  \(x) ifelse(df[x, 1] == df[x, 2], 
              df[x, paste0(df[x, 1], "Pop")], 
              df[x, paste0(df[x, 1], "Pop")] + df[x, paste0(df[x, 2], "Pop")])
  )
```

Similar idea to my above base R solution, but this employs `map2` from the `purrr` package in tidyverse style.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(PartyRel = map2_int(PartyA, PartyB,
                             ~ifelse(.x == .y, 
                                     get(paste0(.x, "Pop")), 
                                     get(paste0(.x, "Pop")) + get(paste0(.y, "Pop"))))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

#### Output

Both of the above give the same result:

```
df
     PartyA    PartyB ChristianPop MuslimPop JewishPop SikhPop BuddhistPop PartyRel
1 Christian    Jewish           12        71         9       0           1       21
2    Muslim    Muslim            1        93         2       0           0       93
3    Muslim Christian           74         5        12       1           2       79
4    Jewish    Muslim           14        86         0       0           0       86
5      Sikh  Buddhist           17        13         4      10          45       55
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but get thrown an error that it can't coerce from a number to an integer? Did not get that issue with a solution further down, but thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Dobbleri Glad you found an answer that worked :) I believe you are using my `map` method, the error occurred because, I believe, there are decimal numbers in your "Pop" columns. `map_int` returns error if they're not integer, you can replace it with `map2_dbl` (or simply `map2()` then `unnest()`).

Answer (score 4):

You can approach this by pivoting the dataset to a long format, summing the rows where the party matches the population, and then pivoting back to wide.

```
library(tidyverse)
df |> 
  mutate(country=row_number())|> 
  pivot_longer(cols=-c(PartyA, PartyB, country),names_pattern = "(.*)Pop") |>
  group_by(country) |> 
  mutate(PartyRel=sum(value[name==PartyA|name==PartyB])) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(PartyA, PartyB,country,PartyRel))



# A tibble: 5 × 9
# Groups:   country [5]
  PartyA    PartyB    country PartyRel Christian Muslim Jewish  Sikh Buddhist
  <chr>     <chr>       <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Christian Jewish          1       21        12     71      9     0        1
2 Muslim    Muslim          2       93         1     93      2     0        0
3 Muslim    Christian       3       79        74      5     12     1        2
4 Jewish    Muslim          4       86        14     86      0     0        0
5 Sikh      Buddhist        5       55        17     13      4    10       45
```

To understand what is happening here have a look at the result after the pivot_longer():

```
# A tibble: 25 × 5
   PartyA    PartyB country name      value
   <chr>     <chr>    <int> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 Christian Jewish       1 Christian    12
 2 Christian Jewish       1 Muslim       71
 3 Christian Jewish       1 Jewish        9
 4 Christian Jewish       1 Sikh          0
 5 Christian Jewish       1 Buddhist      1
 6 Muslim    Muslim       2 Christian     1
 7 Muslim    Muslim       2 Muslim       93
 8 Muslim    Muslim       2 Jewish        2
 9 Muslim    Muslim       2 Sikh          0
10 Muslim    Muslim       2 Buddhist      0
# ℹ 15 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

then it's just a case of identifying the correct rows to sum.

Comment: I think this is the approach I would take IRL. +1

Answer (score 3):

You could use `grep` within `vapply` with `ifelse`:

```
srch <- paste(df$PartyA, df$PartyB, sep = "|")

vapply(srch, \(x) ifelse(is.null(dim(df[, grep(x, names(df))])),
                         df[which(srch == x), grep(x, names(df))],
                         sum(df[which(srch == x), grep(x, names(df))])),
       numeric(1L))

# Christian|Jewish    Muslim|Muslim Muslim|Christian    Jewish|Muslim    Sikh|Buddhist 
#              21               93               79               86               55 

# to assign the results to a new column:
df$newcol <- vapply(srch, \(x) ifelse(is.null(dim(df[, grep(x, names(df))])),
                                      df[which(srch == x), grep(x, names(df))],
                                      sum(df[which(srch == x), grep(x, names(df))])),
                    numeric(1L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of `rowwise` if you prefer tidyverse syntax:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rename_with(~gsub('Pop', '', .x)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Partyrel = sum(c_across(-(1:2))[match(PartyA, names(.)) - 2])) %>%
  mutate(Partyrel = if(PartyA == PartyB) { Partyrel  } else {
    sum(c_across(-(1:2))[match(PartyB, names(.)) - 2]) + Partyrel}) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 8
#>   PartyA    PartyB    Christian Muslim Jewish  Sikh Buddhist Partyrel
#>   <chr>     <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 Christian Jewish           12     71      9     0        1       21
#> 2 Muslim    Muslim            1     93      2     0        0       93
#> 3 Muslim    Christian        74      5     12     1        2       79
#> 4 Jewish    Muslim           14     86      0     0        0       86
#> 5 Sikh      Buddhist         17     13      4    10       45       55
```

Answer (score 3):

For each row grepl the Party columns against the names of `df` giving a logical vector which picks out the relevant columns and finally sum those.

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(PartyRel = 
    sum(pick(everything())[grepl(paste0(PartyA, "|", PartyB), names(.))])) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving

```
# A tibble: 5 × 8
  PartyA    PartyB ChristianPop MuslimPop JewishPop SikhPop BuddhistPop PartyRel
  <chr>     <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Christian Jewish           12        71         9       0           1       21
2 Muslim    Muslim            1        93         2       0           0       93
3 Muslim    Chris…           74         5        12       1           2       79
4 Jewish    Muslim           14        86         0       0           0       86
5 Sikh      Buddh…           17        13         4      10          45       55
>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following base R option

```
ptA <- diag(t(df[paste0(df$PartyA, "Pop")]))
ptB <- diag(t(df[paste0(df$PartyB, "Pop")]))
transform(df, PartyRel = (ptA + ptB) / (1 + (PartyA == PartyB)))
```

which gives

```
     PartyA    PartyB ChristianPop MuslimPop JewishPop SikhPop BuddhistPop
1 Christian    Jewish           12        71         9       0           1
2    Muslim    Muslim            1        93         2       0           0
3    Muslim Christian           74         5        12       1           2
4    Jewish    Muslim           14        86         0       0           0
5      Sikh  Buddhist           17        13         4      10          45
  PartyRel
1       21
2       93
3       79
4       86
5       55
```